# Party model and role, user, profile, group permission scheme

Tags: mysql, database-design, permissions

I have party model database schema:

```
Modules
-------------------------------
id, name, description


Modules_fields <--- Relationship which fields will be in each module
--------------------------------
module_id, field_id


Fields <--- Module_records fields (will define which table field will user see)
--------------------------------
id, name, type


Module_records <--- Entity child - real records
--------------------------------
id, name, description


Entity <--- Central records table - there stores all real record id's
-------------------------------
id, module_id, module_record_id
```

What I need is table relation which defines all possible permissions. Such as:

1. Users can be in groups. Depending on permissions - it can see his records, his group records or all records. Can see, write, edit or delete depending on rights. Row level permissions.
2. User can have role (or roles). Depending on position - can see parent role user records. Row level permissions.
3. Group have profiles. It's easy. Just add Fields-to-GroupProfile table, and set which fields will see profile children. Column level permissions.

My idea is to set up Entity table field user_id - it will define entity creator user. After can search by this user_id in UserGroups and get group_id. Create one more table where will define global permissions, for each module - which group/user will see module. But I don't like such solution.

So I am thinking of adding users, groups, profiles and roles:

```
Profiles - define which fields will user see (User has many profiles), column level
id, name

UsersProfiles - relationships
user_id, profile_id

Users - just user table
id, user_group_id

User_UserGroups - relationships
user_id, user_group_id 

UserGroups - define in which groups user will be, rowlevel (Salesgroup1, Salesgroup2)
id, parent_id

UserRoles - relationships
user_id, role_id

Roles - define user hierarchy (Boss, employee)
id, parent_id

RolesProfiles - relationships
role_id, profile_id
```

Maybe you have better ideas?

Comment: This design (Entity Attribute Value) is an anti-pattern.

Comment: You have better idea of easy expandable system with strong access permission rights? If so - I would be glad to hear.

Comment: Why don't you use standard privilege system offering by your db? Maybe just create db users with restricted permissions to tables in your modules? The most of tables you need exists already in information schema all you need to do is use them in a right way.

Comment: @Orbitum your database already does permissions, even column-level permissions. EAV will kill you when you need to do any kind of analysis. You might want to consider a NoSQL database like mongo if you dislike schemas.

Comment: @Borys I need super-flexible solution, because users can manage database structure by itself. Second thing is that I need row level access for users and groups defined by users and column level (it is made by structure) defined by users too. Maybe I don't know something, but I don't see how to do it with information schema.

Comment: @Neil McGuigan - yes, I was looking for CouchDB (built-in versioning), but I don't know how to properly use it (have no experience). I will check some books about design. Anyway I will need pattern for row and column level access defining. In key-value nosql db, i think, is harder to define access rights. Maybe you have some example for me to better understand? Thanks!